# how to model all relationships between independent variables in R?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I have a small data set with 4 independent (call them a, b, c, d) and 1 dependent variables. Since there are few independent variables, I want to explore all combinations of these variables. There can be only 14 models (a, b, c, d, a+b, a+c, a+d, b+c, b+d, c+d, a+b+c, a+b+d, b+c+d, a+b+c+d).
I build all models by hand and it is time-consuming. Therefore I want to automatize it. Is it possible in R?

glm(dep ~ a, family = "binomial", data = data)
glm(dep ~ b + c, family = "binomial", data = data)
 etc

Answer (score 1):

Using the builtin `anscombe` data frame, this will find the best combination (although stepwise regression is discouraged these days in favour of lasso, elasticnet and other similar approaches based on penalization).

```
fm <- glm(y1 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, data = anscombe)
step(fm)
```

Also see the leaps and glmnet packages.