# 2nd Degree Multivariate Polynomial Regression in R

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

Is there any function for 2nd degree multivariate polynomial regression in R?
Or if not the how to do this in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `poly` to get polynomials inside the `lm` function.

```
lm(dv ~ poly(iv, 2))
```

Comment: Yes, but i have got multiple independent variable and there will be so many combination of selecting variables. And then i have to select best model. It will take a lot of time. I was looking for a function which will check all possible combinations of variable and give best model possible.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56598834/how-to-model-all-relationships-between-independent-variables-in-r/56598937#56598937

Comment: Well, your question is about polynomials... So maybe you should be more precise in what you ask. Of course you can add multiple variables as polynomials and, as @G.Grothendieck said, use stepwise regression.